# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error on running the application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, requirejs

**I am getting an angular module error whenever I am trying to inject dependencies using require.js**

My bower.json file :

```
{
"name": "asa",
"version": "1.0",
"authors": [
"asda"
],
"description": "aaaa",
"dependencies": {
"angular": "1.3.8",
"angular-route": "1.3.8",
"requirejs": "2.1.15",
},
"license": "sss",
"homepage": "index.html",
"ignore": [
"**/.*",
"node_modules",
"bower_components",
"src/main/webapp/resources/bower_components",
"test",
"tests"
]
}
```

**Main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['route']);
app.service('abc', function () {
//some content
});
app.service('def', function( $http, $q ) {
//some content
});
var zzz = app.controller('zzz', function ($scope, $http, $filter, abc, def) {
//controller content
});
zzz.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter','abc','def'];
```

**my data-main file containing the dependencies : main-di.js**

```
require.config({
paths: {
    angular: '../lib/dependencies/bower_components/angular/angular',
    route: '../lib/dependencies/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
    myApp: "person"
},
shim: {
    angular: {
        exports: "angular"
    },
    route: {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    myApp: {
        deps: [ 'angular', 'route']
    }
}
});
require(['myApp'], function () {

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp'), ['myApp']);

});
```

On running the application i get the following error-
**Error :**

```
TypeError: e is undefined
...a("$ngControllerController",f));w(a)}}}n=e.module("ngRoute",  ["ng"]).provider("$r...
```

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp minErr/<@http://localhost:8080/AngularJsInJava/lib/dependencies/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
```

**Can anybody please help me as to why I am getting this error??**

Comment: this is probably due to minification. In controllers use inline array notation for dependency. Check out documentation for further details.https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/guide/di

Comment: Not familiar with require.js but in `zzz.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter','abc','def'];` shouldn't you include $http?

Comment: @MarkoMets - I added $http, but it still doesn't solve my problem  
**Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp**

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct way to define controller.

```
var zzz = app.controller('zzz', function ($scope, $http, $filter, abc, def) {
//controller content
});
```

Create controller this way..

```
app.controller('zzz', ZzzCtrl);
ZzzCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter','abc','def'];
function ZzzCtrl ($scope, $filter, abc, def) {
   // controller code here
}
```

Also if you use minification for your angular Code, you should always use annotations or "$inject"s . Not with controllers only.
eg.

```
angular.module('someModule').service('someService',['$someInjection', function($someInjection){}])
```